# Form Validation Select

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I use this select

```
<div class="formRight">              
   <?php
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adm ORDER by name");
      if(mysql_error())
      {
         print(mysql_error());
      }
      echo'<select id="name" name="name" data-placeholder="Select" class="select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">';
      echo'<option selected>[Select]</option>';
      {
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
         echo'<option value="'.$row['name_id'].'">'.$row['name_a'].'</option>';
      }
      echo'</select>';
   ?>
</div>
```

I have successfull installed a JQUERY Validate Plugin, all work right except for Select.
Any chance to apply this?

I use `class="validate[required]`

Comment: Which jquery validation plugin? There are TONS of them out there.

Comment: What is happening and what do you expect?

Comment: Please note that mysql is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). I'd advise using pdo or mysqli instead.

Comment: Plugin is query.validate.js, by default 1st opton on dropdown selected is [Select] and after options extracts from database.

I'm like to force user to select an option as required fiedl because user can be submitted with [Select] option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change two things:

1)  Add a `"required"` `class` into the `<select>` element.

2)  You must have `value=""` on the first `<option>` item.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/VaDrD/**

**PHP**:

```
  echo'<select id="name" name="name" data-placeholder="Select" class="select required" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">';
  echo'<option value="" selected="selected">[Select]</option>';
  {
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
     echo'<option value="'.$row['name_id'].'">'.$row['name_a'].'</option>';
  }
  echo'</select>';
```

**Rendered HTML**:

```
<select id="name" name="name" data-placeholder="Select" class="select required" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">[Select]</option>
    <option value="xxx">option 1</option>
    <option value="xxx">option 2</option>
    <option value="xxx">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really understand what you want.
Are you looking for this?

```
 <select required id="name" name="name" data-placeholder="Select"
 class="select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
```

Answer (score -1):

I have find a possible solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var year = $(#year option:selected).val();
if(year == "")
{
$("#msg").html("Please select a year");
return false;
}
});
});
```